# broswer blocked cookie when sending request

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, frontend

Recently I have been developing 2 front end apps on my local desktop. I don't have a lot of experience in the front end, what makes me confused is that the cookie value is correct but only one app that the cookie was blocked from the browser. I will be grateful if anyone could help me. Thank you!!

- Browser: chrome
- what I want to do is to send the request to another service in localhost with a cookie
- result so far: localhost:3000 send the request without cookie whereas localhost:3001 works fine. (found the request by filtered request with `has blocked cookie` in browser)

what I have tried so far:

- disable all extensions
- use incognito mode
- check cookie value in both 3000 and 3001, which is correct

I also tried to send the request by insomnia, it works fine as well when I send the request with cookies.

I also noticed that in my browser in the URL section the localhost:3000 displays not secure, not sure if it makes the difference? I have manually allowed the cookie for localhost:3000 by changing the setting. I am not sure why the browser only block the cookie in localhost:3000, is there any way to unblock it by tuning the browser?[image]

[image]

Comment: I think, when cookie saved in browser with secure domain so unsecure domain can't access that cookie .for example if you save cookie with the name session in secure domain then unsecure domain can't access it so browser can not send cookie to server.so both of them must be secure.first clear all cookie from https and http then make both of them secure.

Comment: @MohammadrezaMohammadi thank you for your reply. I found that I assigned wrong variable when I `prepareUrls` (library: react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils), I pass the `https` rather than `http`.

Answer (score 0):

I assigned the wrong variable when I `prepareUrls` (library: react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils), I pass the `https` rather than `http`.